# isfile not recognising files python 2.5

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code:

```
with open('EcoDocs TK pdfs.csv', 'rb') as pdf_in:
    pdflist = csv.reader(pdf_in, quotechar='"')
    for row in pdflist:
        if row[1].endswith(row[2]):#check if file type is appended to file name
            pathname = ''.join(row[0:2])
        else:
            pathname = ''.join(row)
        if os.path.isfile(pathname):
            filehash = md5.md5(file(pathname).read()).hexdigest()
```

It reads in file paths, file names and file types from a csv file. It then checks to see if the file type is appended to the file name, before joining the file path and file name. It then checks to see if the file exists, before doing something with the file. There are about 5000 file names in the csv file, but isfile only returns True for about half of these. I've manually checked that some of those isfile returns False for exist. As all the data is read in, there shouldn't be any problems with escape characters or single backslashes, so I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas? An example of the csv file format is below, as well as an example of some of the `pathname`that isfile can't find.

csv file-

```
c:\2dir\a. dir\d dir\lo dir\fu dir\wdir\5dir\,5_l B.xls,.xls
c:\2dir\a. dir\d dir\lo dir\fu dir\wdir\5dir\,5_l A.pdf,.pdf
```

pathname created-

```
c:\2dir\a. dir\d dir\lo dir\fu dir\wdir\5dir\5_l B.xls
c:\2dir\a. dir\d dir\lo dir\fu dir\wdir\5dir\5_l A.pdf
```

Thanks.

Comment: You really have `a. dir` on your disk? Written exactly like that?

Comment: No, those file paths are just examples as my real data is commercially sensitive. The characters before each 'dir' do correspond to my data though, just to allow evaluation of any special/escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely assume that `os.path.isfile()` works correctly. Here is my process to debug issues like this:

1. Add a `print(pathname)` before I use it.
2. Eyeball the output. Does anything look suspicious?
3. Copy the output into the clipboard -> <kbd>Win+R</kbd>`cmd`<kbd>Return</kbd>`dir`<kbd>Space</kbd>`"` + paste into new command prompt + `"`<kbd>Return</kbd>
   That checks whether the path is really correct (finds slight mistakes that eyeballing will miss). It also helps to validate the insane [DOS naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) which are still enforced even on Windows.
4. if this also works, the next step is to check file and folder permissions: Make sure the user that runs the script actually has permissions to see and read the file.

**EDIT** Paths on Windows are ... complicated. An important detail, for example, is that "." is a very, very special character. The name "a.something very long" isn't valid in the command prompt because it demands that you have **at most** three characters after the last "." in a file name! You're just lucky that it doesn't demand that the name *before* the last dot is [at most 8 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Conclusion: You must be very, very, very careful with "strange characters" in file names and paths on Windows. The only characters which are safe are [listed in this document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aaron. That's pretty much the same debugging process I followed, except I just pasted the output into windows explorer and this it didn't have any problems. I have just tried pasting it into cmd like you suggested, and it is coming up with the error `The filename or extension is too long`. I wasn't aware there was a maximu length of filename. Is there someway to overcome/modify this limit in windows?

Comment: @joel: Ah. That means you have a file name which isn't DOS compatible. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, Aaron. I've fixed the issue with the filename being too long, `\\?\` did the trick. Using cmd to check the file like you suggested certainly helped so I have accepted your answer. I can carry on debugging the script now, and will use the info you supplied in your last edit. Thanks very much.